# Change the background of an element when user dragging it

Tags: javascript, css

How to apply some css property on dragging element when user selected it and start dragging it, when element in drag able mode i want to change it text color and background.

Comment: What have you tried? How did you make the element draggable? What event are you listening on?

Comment: Yes, i am listing (dragstart) method.

Comment: when `mousedown`, apply class, when `mouseup` remove class, in your case, dragstart, dragend

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:active` pseudo-class.

```css
[draggable="true"] {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #666;
}

[draggable="true"]:active {
  color: #0f0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">
  some text in a div for coloring demonstration.
</div>
```

I only tested in the latest version of Chrome, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

1) Identify when the dragging starts. If you are using your own library it will probably be the place where you add event listener `mousedown`.

2) Identify when the dragging ends. This will also be the place where you add event listener `mouseup`.

Now all you have to do is:

- add class when dragging starts
- remove class when dragging ends

jQuery has easy API that will let you do that:

```
$('.your-element-class-name').addClass('.your-background-class');
```

If you are using someone else's library, please share the name of the library here. However, you still need to do the same thing. Add class when dragging starts and remove when it ends. There will probably an API for that.